# Validate Login credential out of joomla! core structure

Tags: php, joomla

I am developing a plug-in for joomla! but considering the complexity of the script I designed it out of the core structure.

Now the only problem I am having is to let users login just once as administrators and following my plug-in folder, which is misplaced, only if they have permission.

my plug-in is in:( path[dot]com/test) folder everything works fine in there but is available to the public.

So far i have tried from the (test/index.php) this code :

```
// Load Joomla! configuration file
require_once('../configuration.php');
// Create a JConfig object
$config = new JConfig();
//import variables
$dbhostname     = $config->host;
$dbusername     = $config->user; 
$dbpassword     = $config->password;
$dbdatabase     = $config->db;
$dbprefix       = $config->dbprefix;
$secret         = $config->secret;

// Get these from your form...

   $username_for_check = 'admin'; // this username should be in your database = change it

   $password_for_check = 'passw'; //this password should be in your database encrypted = change it

//connect to db
   $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbdatabase);

   if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT j.username,j.password FROM '.$dbprefix.'users j WHERE j.username="'.$username_for_check.'" LIMIT 1;')) {

      if ($result->num_rows == 0){
         echo 'Username does not exist.';
      }
      else{
         while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

            //Grab username and password from table #__users
            $joomla_user = $row->username;
            $joomla_pass = $row->password;


            $pass_array = explode(':',$row->password);// <== Here not sure!!
            //but it should be the magic behind it.. for me doesn't work  in joomla 3.5 and above apparently as encryption method changed
            //my password does not have a colon in between

            //\\===\ Those are just echos to visually check if the password was matched /==//\\

            echo '[USER:] '.$joomla_user.'<br>';

            echo '[PASS:] '.$joomla_pass.'<br>';

            echo '[HASH:] '.$joomla_hash = $pass_array[0].'<br>';

            echo '[SALT:] '.$joomla_salt = $pass_array[1].'<br>';

            echo '[SECRET:] '.$secret.'<br>'; //secret maybe of help, just put it ready for testing

            echo '[CHECK:] '.md5($password_for_check.$joomla_salt).'<br>';
            //=======================================================================//
         }

         if($joomla_hash == md5($password_for_check.$joomla_salt)){ //Old approch for validating according to various prehistoric posts

            echo 'Username and password combination validated.';

         }
         else{
            echo 'Invalid password for username.';
         }

      }

   }
   else {
     echo 'LOGIN VALIDATION: MySQL Error - '.$mysqli->error;
   }
   //close db
   $mysqli->close();
```

Trying to return a match and verify registered users before continuing.

I hope someone have a solution for this on 3.5 and above.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the best way to do it is like this hope it would help someone:

```
<?php
// Load Joomla! configuration file
require_once('../configuration.php');
// Create a JConfig object
$config = new JConfig();
//import variables
$dbhostname     = $config->host;
$dbusername     = $config->user;  
$dbpassword     = $config->password;
$dbdatabase     = $config->db;
$dbprefix       = $config->dbprefix;

// Get these from your form...
    $username_for_check = 'admin'; // this username should be in your database = change it
    $password_for_check = '1234'; //this password should be in your database encrypted = change it

    //Something like that from your form
    //$username_for_check = $_POST['access_login']; 
    //$password_for_check = $_POST['access_password']; 
//connect to db
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbdatabase);
    if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT j.username,j.password FROM '.$dbprefix.'users j WHERE j.username="'.$username_for_check.'" LIMIT 1;')) {
        if ($result->num_rows == 0){
            echo 'Username does not exist.';
        }
        else{
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                //Grab username and password from table #__users
                $joomla_user = $row->username;
                $joomla_pass = $row->password;
            }
            if(password_verify($password_for_check , $joomla_pass)){ 
                echo 'Username and password combination validated.';
            }
            else{
                echo 'Invalid password for username.';
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
      echo 'LOGIN VALIDATION: MySQL Error - '.$mysqli->error;
    }
    //close db
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```